# show loading status with ajax call

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript solution to show some sort of status while an ajax request is taking place. I tried `document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<h2>Loading....</h2>";` but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```
function codesDelete(id) {
    var ajax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<h2>Data Deleted!</h2>";
        }
    }

    // this is what i tried
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<h2>Loading....</h2>";


    ajax.open("GET", "code.php?id=" + id, true);
    ajax.send();

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("status").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's when/done. Start your status indicator and then use when/done like this:

```
// start the status indicator wherever it's appropriate    
StartStatusIndicator();

//Make your ajax call
$.when($.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...more stuff...
    success: function (json) {
        ...even more stuff...
    }
})).done(function () {
    KillYourStatusIndicator();
});
```

The code inside `done` gets fired when the ajax call is finished.

Comment: Just learned this myself a couple months ago. Thought it was pretty cool. =)

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I like that it is generic enough that you can pretty well use it anywhere, for pretty well any thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another method you could do is to use the `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks on jQuery.ajax, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend:function(){
        // Create and insert your loading message here as you desire
        // For example, a version of what you were trying to do would be:
        $("#status").html("<h2>Loading....</h2>");
    },
    // ... whatever other things you need, such as a success callback, data, url, etc
    complete: function(){
       // Remove your loading message here, for example:
       $("#status").html("");
    }
});
```

As the names suggest, `beforeSend` will be executed before the AJAX call is made. `Complete` will execute, regardless whether the AJAX succeeded or failed, after the call is finished.